# How to send notifications using Facebook's SDK for instant games?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been working on an instant game for Facebook. All I want is to send a notification that invites the user to play again. I've been checking out documentation for it but it is very unclear on that matter.

I am already using the SDK for instant games and got it running, but I have no idea on how to use the graph API to only send a notification. I don't know in which file I have to put the code for it, nor where to reference it in the index.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a messenger bot to be able to message users.
check this is the bot docs
[1]: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/bot-setup/